# Flutter Tab with Tooltip

Tags: flutter, tabs, tooltip

I'm making a Flutter web app.

I have a number of tabs, and if there are too many the text in them can be obscured and so I want a tooltip when the users hovers over it they can always see the full text.

My existing working code to build my list of tabs is like this :

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
   String tabTitle = option[i].text;
   tabs.add( Tab(text: tabTitle) );
}
```

I want to do something like this :

```dart
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
   String tabTitle = option[i].text;
   tabs.add( 
        Tooltip( 
          message: tabTitle, 
          child: Tab(text: tabTitle), 
        ),
      );
}
```

but that says "**The argument type 'Tooltip' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Tab'.**"

#### Is there any way to have tooltips on the individual Tabs in a TabBar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have declared `tabs` as `List<Tab>`,
then just change it to `List<Widget>` it will work,

```
tabs: [
        Tooltip(message: 'message', child: Tab(text: 'test'),),
        Tab(text: 'Test1'),
        Tab(text: 'Test2')
   ]
```

In your case

```
final tabs = <Widget>[];
```

then just add tabs to it.

```
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
   String tabTitle = option[i].text;
   tabs.add( 
        Tooltip( 
          message: tabTitle, 
          child: Tab(text: tabTitle), 
        ),
      );
}
```

Comment: Please mark it as answer if it helps, Thank you.

Comment: Of course!  Well spotted.  I feel silly for having not picked that up from the message - thank you for figuring it out for me.